# Problem: "[action]" does not accept any expressions

Tags: struts2

I tried to use the following code :

```
<li>
    <% for (int i=0; i<parentList.size(); i++) {
        Role p = parentList.get(i); 
    %>
        <li><a href="<s:url action="<%=p.getFunclink() %>"/>"><%=p.getFuncname() %></a>
        <ul>
            <% for (int j=0; j<roleList.size(); j++) {
                Role c = roleList.get(j);
                if (!c.getFuncid().equalsIgnoreCase(c.getParentfunc()) && c.getParentfunc().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFuncid()))
                {
                %>
                    <li><a href="<s:url action="<%=c.getFunclink() %>"/>"><%=c.getFuncname() %></a>                     
                <%
                }
            }   
            %>
        </ul>
    <% } %>
    </li>
```

but it throw error:

```
    JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /menu.jsp:  
/menu.jsp(95,17) --> JSPG0124E: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute "[action]" does not accept any expressions. Value of expression is: "[%=p.getFunclink() %]".
```

How can i fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Struts tags cannot accept expressions, thus:

```
<s:url action="<%=p.getFunclink() %>"/>
```

is invalid.

- First, avoid using scriptlets at all.
- Second, look into using the [`<s:iterator/>`](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/iterator.html) tag to iterate over your collections.